# R Shiny - fast counting rows in table stored in PostgreSQL

Tags: r, postgresql, shiny

I'm building so called BI application in R shiny. I have a problem with tables with over 20.000.000 rows. I'm using dplyr library and `tally()` function, despite this it takes 5 minutes to count rows for specific id. Does anyone know better option, library to do that? Maybe I shouldn't build this app in shiny, and try other?

Comment: its very bad idea to load the tables this size into R, they are going to be in-memory taking a lot of RAM. Just do all the querying in PostgreSQL and only return the aggregated results

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is Shiny, data.table may be a little faster than dplyr but I think the main issue here is to try to execute the query in Postgres and avoid moving the data in memory.